# WPF returning 403 Forbidden error but postman does not

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to consume a RESTful web API. When I use Postman I connect successfully but I get a 403 error when I connect from WPF. Here's my asynchronous function from WPF:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://uat.fitygrouponline.com/onlineopeningservice/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AppId", "12345");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AppKey", "123456");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


    long re = 2017;

    string date = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(newdat.Text));//check this format

    Dictionary<string, object> para = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    para.Add("Title", title.Text);//required
    para.Add("Complete ", "Yes");//required
    para.Add("ReferenceNo", re);//required
    para.Add("Resident", "Yes");

    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(para);
    var resp = await client.PostAsync("api/opening/create", new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));


    if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // use this if you want object type returned
        content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result));

        prog.IsActive = false;
        cont.Content = content.responseMessageField;
        MessageBox.Show(content.NumberField);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(resp.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

I get the 403 error when i check `resp.IsSuccessStatusCode`. How can I fix this?

Comment: What kind of authentication is there on the web service? Also, what does your request in Postman look like?

Comment: Check your keys, and recheck it ...

Comment: A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).

If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access. The client SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same credentials. The client MAY repeat the request with new or different credentials. However, a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.

Comment: @nikunjMnage exactly same keys used exactly same way i did on post man.

Comment: @GabrielLuci is there a way i should show you how i made the request with post man? no auth, two key-value headers, post request and i get a successful response. i just don't know why using same headers, same parameters and same url will deny me access on wpf

Comment: It may be how you are sending headers. try Different codes from online. I think that's the best way to move forward. @IsraelEruoghene

Comment: Something has to be different. Do you have a development copy of the API that you can debug and step through? You could put a breakpoint in `Application_BeginRequest` and examine the `Request` payload.

Comment: @GabrielLuci no i don't. i'm not the developer for the api and his documentation is no good. Although he mentioned he used finnacle for the API

Comment: Are you able to use Wireshark on the server to monitor traffic? It'll only work if you have admin rights and if you are not using SSL.

Comment: Guys, i just discovered that the API developer gave me wrong parameter signature. i.e. he asked me to use a long instead of an int. so the call could not find the function. Thanks so much for your assistance. Much love.